# Illegal offset type when checking if array is set / empty / is array PHP

Tags: php, arrays

Below is an example of my array and in my code I'm trying to check if `$champions` (name of this whole array) `isset$champions[$champion]['General']` and I get this error I need to check it since General array won't always exist

```
array (size=1)
  'Aatrox' => 
    array (size=1)
      'General' => 
        array (size=2)
          'Change' => 
            array (size=2)
              0 => string 'test.' (length=5)
              1 => string 'TEZd' (length=4)
          'Type' => 
            array (size=2)
              0 => string 'buff' (length=4)
              1 => string 'buff' (length=4)


foreach($champions as $champion){
        if(isset($champions[$champion]['General'])){
              ..... 
        }

}
```

Comment: Try: if(is_array($champions....

Comment: @MaggsWeb tried that as well and tried empty same error every time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
foreach($champions as $key => $champion){
    if(isset($champions[$key]['General'])){
          ..... 
    }

}
```

$champion would be the array containing the key 'General' if you want to access the array by index then you need to use the key instead.

Your other option would be `isset($champion['General'])`

Comment: In the end I used foreach(array_keys($champions) as $champion){ but ill accept your answer in 3 mins as it is correct as well